# Reduce function with bracket key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm confused what the following line of code means:

```
if(!acc[key])
```

This is my interpretation of the line:

If the `key` is not in `acc` then set the `key` with value array and jump out of the if statement. Then push the `obj` in `acc` key value.

In case the `key` is in `acc`, skip the if statement and use another memory `acc[key]` and set the `key` which is in `acc` and set value with `obj`. (NEEDS MAJOR REVISION)

Is my explanation correct?

```js
var people = [{
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 20
  }
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    var key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
      acc[key].push(obj)
    }
    return acc;

  }, {});
}
var groupedPeople = groupBy(people, 'age')
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedPeople))
```

Answer (score 3):

The square brackets `[]` are used for [dynamic property notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) (also known as computed property names). It's like this:

```
var obj = { foo: "bar" };
var propertyWeWant = "foo"; //We want to get obj.foo - the value "bar"
console.log(obj.propertyWeWant); //Returns undefined
console.log(obj[propertyWeWant]); //Returns bar
```

The function `groupBy` takes an array of people, and returns the people *grouped by* the passed property (in this case, `age`):

```js
var people = [{
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 20
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    age: 20
  }
];

function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    var key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj)
    return acc;

  }, {});
}
var groupedPeople = groupBy(people, 'age')
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedPeople))
```

Comment: acc[key].push(obj) should be out of the if statement, otherwise it is not make sense.

Comment: whats this if(!acc[key]) means

Comment: why the result is start with 20 not 21

Answer (score 1):

The `!acc[key]` mean it will return `false` if the property `key` (it is dynamic like @Jack Bashford said) doesn't exist in object `acc`.
The `reduce` will work

1. `acc` init with {}
2. loop into the first object: `key` = '21', but `acc['21']` is `undefined` run the block code of `if`
3. 2nd: key = '20' and `!acc[key]` return true ~> set `acc['20'] = obj`
4. last object. key = '20', but `acc['20']` has value at step 3 ~> skip block code and return `acc`
5. return `acc` with 2 key '20' and '21'

The reason the result starts with 20 first is I think the browser want to print the property of the object which sorted by the alphabet.

Comment: please explain if acc[key].push(obj) is out of the if clause and return acc

Comment: First, `reduce` actually is a loop and the value returned in a callback function of `reduce` will be used in the next iterate. Second, `acc[key].push(obj)` should be outside the `if` clause because inside is for new `key` case only, if you let that statement here, another object with the same key will be ignored (`Jane's object`). Then you just init the value `acc[key] = []` in `if` clause and push the object to the key for all the item. Return the new object at the end (`return acc`)

Answer (score 0):

```
    "HR": [
        {
            name: janki
            sal: 50000
        },
        {
            name: er
            sal: 47852
        },
        {
            name: sfd
            sal: 25685
        }
    ],
    "Management": [
        {
            name: janki
            sal: 50000
        },
        {
            name: er
            sal: 47852
        },
        {
            name: sfd
            sal: 25685
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).